# How to insert Integer data with JavaFX 8?

Tags: nullpointerexception, javafx-8

I have a form and want to insert integer data . This is the POJO :

IntNumberData.class

```
...
private final IntegerProperty num;

public IntNumberData() {
    this(null);
}

public IntNumberData(Integer num) {
    this.num    = new SimpleIntegerProperty(num);
}

public Integer getNum() {
    return num.get();
}

public void setNum(Integer num) {
    this.num.set(num);
}

public IntegerProperty numProperty() {
    return num;
}
...
```

Also created the other classes and when I try to add data I get the message :

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at net.websimp.numdata.model.Intnumberdata.(Intnumberdata.java:11)  at net.websimp.numdata.controller.IntnumberdataController.handleNewNum(IntnumberdataController.java:35)

I tested all references , but when change the type Integer to String works. why that?

Comment: Since we only see a code snippet, I am not sure about an answer.  I strongly suggest not to use this(null) to initialize. You most certanly get a NPE because you yourself call new SimpleIntegerProperty(null). Try to use a dummy like 0 or work with Optional<R> class...

Comment: I understand. I will try again as you said.

Comment: Do you import import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
because your NPE looks strange... Coming from net-websimp... :S Maybe you imported the wrong class...

Comment: It would help if you could show which line is line 11, and what code you are executing to generate the Exception.

Comment: Right about import, now works correctly. A fact is that there are many classes, made ​​a mistake in not predict and treat forms entries for the data types . The fact was that in the main class, there is a method that calls an empty constructor but with IntegerProperty he does not accept referrals when it is passed to another method of a controller. Thank for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor for [`SimpleIntegerProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/SimpleIntegerProperty.html#SimpleIntegerProperty-int-) takes an `int` (i.e. **not an `Integer`**). So your constructor

```
public IntNumberData(Integer num) {
    this.num    = new SimpleIntegerProperty(num);
}
```

implicitly unboxes `num`, i.e. it effectively compiles to

```
public IntNumberData(Integer num) {
    this.num    = new SimpleIntegerProperty(num.intValue());
}
```

which will throw a `NullPointerException` if `num` is `null`.

You can instead do

```
public IntNumberData(Integer num) {
    this.num    = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    this.num.setValue(num);
}
```

but note that the implementation will set this to `0` if `null` is passed in (see the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/WritableIntegerValue.html#setValue-java.lang.Number-)).

If you genuinely want a property of type `Integer` that supports null values, then you should use an [`ObjectProperty<Integer>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/SimpleObjectProperty.html) instead of an `IntegerProperty`.

Comment: Doing as in the last example , it generates an error because of the class attributes . They are marked as private final . But thanks for the help.

Comment: I used ObjectProperty and is now working properly. Thanks man. Thank guys.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your error comes from the null (I am quite sure actually cause I tested now).

Run this snippet to see it clash:

```
Integer n = null;
SimpleIntegerProperty p = new SimpleIntegerProperty(n);`
```

You could for example just initalize it with 0, or is that in your case not applicable?

With `Optional<R>`you could hand out optionals... Just give a look at [this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/optional/java-8-optional-example/)